# What is the rough upper bound to find nth prime? Also give the maximum error.

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

*At first please don't mark this as duplicate. I couldn't get a satisfactory answer in previous questions.*

I want a simple upper bound calculating formula for n-th prime which should not have integration or other complex thing. I also need the maximum error it can produce. The error can be high but the thing I need is formula must be simple..
I need this formula to write an algorithm.

Comment: This isn't an upper bound, but approximately the first $\lfloor e^n\rfloor$ numbers contain $n$ primes.

Comment: what counts as complex ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I mean a formula which can be directly evaluated using simple calculator or computer.

Comment: That depends on operator skill, as I can do 25+ year loan math on an calculator with M+ and MR keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For explicit bounds we have

$$
p_n \le n\bigg(\log n + \log\log n - 1 + \frac{\log\log n - 2.1}{\log n}\bigg) \text{    for $x \ge 3$}
$$
and 
$$
p_n \ge n\bigg(\log n + \log\log n - 1 + \frac{\log\log n - 2}{\log n}\bigg) \text{    for $x \ge 688,383$}
$$
and for an error estimate, we have
$$
p_n = n\bigg(\log n + \log\log n - 1 + \frac{\log\log n - 2}{\log n}
+ \frac{\log\log^2 n - 6\log\log x + 11}{2\log^2 n} \bigg) \\
+ O\bigg(\frac{\log\log^3 n}{\log^3 n}\bigg)
$$

**Reference**: https://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1002/1002.0442v1.pdf